# Apk install andorid box

Tags: installation, apk

Im trying to install kodi 18.9 apk file on my a95x android 9 box

I cannot seem to get it to work.  Tried everything

Turn off google protect
Allow unknown sources
Cleared cache goodle services  amd google play

Is there something I should chamge in apk manifest

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.